# Compressing / minify html in C# MVC

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, compression, minify

I have a website set up in Umbraco V7, where I want to minify all html that is sent to the client. I've tried using WebMarkupMin through RegisterGlobalFilters, but nothing happens.

My code

*~/App_Start/FilterConfig.cs*

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new MinifyHtmlAttribute());
    }
}
```

*~/Global.asax.cs*

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

If please help me. I do not know what I'm missing. Or if the way I have tried to do it is hopeless, I am also open to hear about other ways of achieving this.

Comment: Have you tried placing the attribute on specific actions to see if it works? It might be that registering it globally isn't supported. It probably *should* work as you have it, but their own [documentation](https://webmarkupmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebMarkupMin%200.9.2#WebMarkupMinAspNetMvcExtensions_Chapter) only shows it used decorating the actions directly.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work either. But I think this has something to do with Umbraco. Maybe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try a solution based on a HttpModule. (Works for MVC and Webforms)
For example this one is very simple: [minify-html-for-asp-net](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/minify-html-for-asp-net/)

Answer (score 1):

In [WebMarkupMin 1.X](http://webmarkupmin.codeplex.com/) it was impossible to register instances of classes `MinifyHtmlAttribute`, `MinifyXhtmlAttribute`, `MinifyXmlAttribute` and `CompressContentAttribute` as global filters, but in [WebMarkupMin 2.X](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin) solved this problem.

Uninstall the [WebMarkupMin.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMarkupMin.Mvc/) module and replace it by the [WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc/) module. Also I recommend you to read the [“How to upgrade applications to version 2.X”](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/How-to-upgrade-applications-to-version-2.X) section of documentation.

Comment: I'm trying this right now but I don't see any results... did you make it work somehow?

Comment: @rosko, maybe you did not switch the web application in release mode.

Comment: yes, I forgot to disable the debug mode in my Web.config before testing it:) Now it works in release mode. Thank you!